# Enabling Hyper-V in HP Z800 BIOS

Tags: hyper-v, bios

I should be able to enable Hyper-V for my new HP Z800, but I simply cannot find the switch in BIOS. Does anybody know what they've called it this time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I found it buried under Security > Device Security. Guess I should have read TFM (http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&taskId=115&prodSeriesId=3718645&prodTypeId=12454&objectID=c01718191).

Answer (score 0):

It is not under device security but system security